# Can't get actual "valid" property in method using ref and VeeValidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I have `<ValidationObserver ref="observer">` that has some `ValidationProviders` inside. To get "valid" property in method `getUnit()` I use `this.$refs.observer.fields["Unit"].valid`, but at the moment it doesn't have actual "valid" property yet. It gets it a little bit later. I have to do something depending on the validity of this field.

So how do I get actual "valid" property the field, if it hasn't got it yet?

It creates some kind of delay in one symbol, but I need to change the state of "Continue" button immediately.

Delay of state of "Continue" button:
[image: delay of state of "Continue" button]

Comment: have you try to set the `data-vv-delay` option? http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/examples/debounce.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields do not get registered until after the first render, so you need to add some checks to make sure your field is present before checking against. I recommend to do that in the template and avoid using `$refs` as they are not reactive.

```html
<!-- If used from the Provider slot props, it will always be present -->
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ valid }">
  {{ valid }}
</ValidationProvider>
```

If you need access to `valid` property from outside the `Provider` slot, you can also access it on the `ValidationObserver` slot props. But you would need to check for its existence first.

```html
<!-- If used from the Provider slot props, it will always be present -->
<ValidationObserver v-slot="{ fields }">
  {{ fields.unit && fields.unit.valid }}
</ValidationObserver>
```

This assumes the field `vid` or `name` is `unit`.